# Will a live app that currently does not have IAP be affected if I add an IAP in iTC?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

To clarify, I currently have a live app that does not implement in app purchases. Assuming I don't update the app in any way, does creating a new IAP in iTunes Connect affect my end users in any way?

Since there isn't any code deployed in the app that uses IAP I'm 99.99% sure it won't, but I want to be absolutely sure before I press the button. My heart rate always goes up a little bit when I'm mucking around with a live app. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding IAP will most definetly not affect existing instances of your live app.